# Baofeng BF-888s radios don't talk to Baofeng BF-888s+ radios

Tags: baofeng, equipment-operation

I had originally bought a set of BaoFeng BF-888s+ radios that perform very well and perfectly suit my needs.

Needing more, I bought another set, this time buying BaoFeng BF-888s radios.

(Same model code, except the "+" at the end, apparently just a restyling).

The new radios don't talk to the old radios, despite being on the same channel. Both radio sets work well among themselves, but the two sets don't communicate with each other.

I bought both sets from Amazon, delivered to a US address. I live in a country where regulation is not an issue (not the US).

How can I make both sets talk to each other?

I've read somewhere that these BaoFeng radios have a programming cable (that I don't have). *If* these radios can actually talk to each other, I would very much prefer to fix them without using a cable (e.g., using keys on the units in a way that allows configuring them), as I don't have one, and getting one would be both expensive and time consuming considering where I am now.
Otherwise, if getting a cable is the only option, is this a standard cable that can be bought in computers/electronics shops? Is their software readily available?

Comment: I believe that radio has 16 channels.  Even though they're not programmed identically, have you tried to see if any of the channels match up?  Perhaps channel 3 on one pair matches channel 14 on the other.

Comment: @Lance I did, but no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you fell into one of the traps of the Chinese radios! You can't really assume what frequencies are they programmed with.

Basically, the radios are designed to be programmed with a certain set of frequencies, just like so-called "professional" radios of many other manufacturers. The "channel" on the radio is just a memory location, into which a frequency is written. As you figured out, you can't rely on them being the same across the models, so you'll need to make sure that on both sets of radios, same channels contain same frequencies.

Unfortunately, just like with many other "professional" radios, BF-888s aren't programmable without the cable. For "professional" radios, this part would normally be done by your dealer, in accordance with your license, but since you're getting the radios yourself, then you also need to do the programming on your own, or find a radio dealer close to you who might do it for you. IF you can't, then you need to get the programming cable and do it yourself.

The programming software is readily available. It might come on the CD with the cable, or you might need to get it yourself. [Here](http://www.miklor.com/BF888/)'s a nice page with some software versions. Another option would be to use program called [CHIRP](http://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/Download).

Comment: Thumbs up for CHIRP. And if I remember correctly, the programming cable is just a dumb TTL converter with a 3.5mm connector. Maybe one can find schematics/howtos online. Anyway, those things can't be expensive on amazon.

Comment: @MarcusMüller oh no, it's super cheap on Amazon. but I'm on an island in the middle of nowhere and shipping will kill me.

Comment: @AndreajaKo great answer and super useful links, thanks!

Comment: @magma … that's why I mentioned the possibility to build one yourself

Comment: @Marcus Müller Yeah, the cable is just a TTL converter, but sometimes, they also have USB to serial converter as well. Those cables are the sources for much of the issues and mythology behind the programming cables, since they quite often have dodgy chips inside.

Comment: @magma Coming from a country to which shipping is usually very expensive, I fully understand your issues. Good luck! You might want to try searching for local electronic component stores. I don't know what the prices are in your area, but in mine, components for making the cable yourself would be around $5. If the shipping situation is so drastic, then it might be worth considering making the cable yourself.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. One of the links in AndrejaKo's answer has detailed schematics (well, it's just 3 wires, as long as you have a usb/ttl converter). I happen to have a USB-to-TTL dongle in a drawer, I can easily find the two jacks locally, and I will definitely build the cable myself. I know nothing about radios, but I'm luckily very comfortable with programming devices, so as long as I don't shortcircuit the unit with my poor soldering skills, I should be set. Thanks thanks thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

All good answers and comments given.

However, what strikes me is that *you do not know what frequencies you are using*.

Therefore it could very well be, and very likely, that you are using frequencies which you are not licensed for.

If that is the case:

- It is ILLEGAL to use frequencies which you are not licensed for, or which are outside the allowable license-exempt allocations in your country.
- It is DANGEROUS to use frequencies which you are not sure of, as they may interfere with official communications, such as aviation, maritime, emergency services, and other licensed services.

If you do not know what frequencies you are using, and/or if you are not licensed for those frequencies, I would **strongly recommend that you STOP using the radio**

**[Edit based on commments]**

That out of the way, the answers and comments already given are detailing **how** to program frequencies, but do not detail **what** frequencies you should program and use.

> I live in a country where regulation is not an issue (not the US).

OK, even when living in a country without strict regulation about radio-usage, you **should** try to adhere to some international agreements.

Example:

- you should not use any frequency which is in use by general aviation operations.
  108 MHz-136 MHz
- you should not use any frequency which is in use by general marine operations. 153 MHz - 163 MHz

Furthermore I would advice you to figure out your local emergency services, by either asking, searching on the internet. I would stay away from those.

Lastly, stay away from local broadcasters. This to avoid inteference either by you or to you.

Hard to believe that "regulation is not an issue", but you have not disclosed what country it is; so other than general statements on what frequencies to use is probably as best an answer you can get.

Comment: While this is relevant advice, it does not actually answer the question. Please consider expanding your answer.

Comment: @KevinReidAG6YO, fair enough; answer updated.

Answer (score -2):

Different countries have allowed different frequencies to be used. Here is a chart comparing USA and Canada. It might help you for example have one radio on channel one the other on channel 9 . 
FRS is the USA      GMRS is Canada
FRS/GMRS Channels
Channel numbers commonly used on 22 channel FRS/GMRS dual service radios are shown in the leftmost column. Most radios of this type are not capable of repeater operation and do not include the repeater input frequencies.
Common Channel ↓    Frequency  ↓    FRS Chan.  ↓    FRS Max Output ↓    FRS Max Bandwidth  ↓    GMRS Chan.  ↓   GMRS Max Ouput ↓    GMRS Max Bandwidth ↓    Usage/Notes ↓
01  462.5625    FRS 1   500 mW  12.5 kHz    GMRS 9  5 W 25 kHz  Unofficial national calling channel
02  462.5875    FRS 2   500 mW  12.5 kHz    GMRS 10 5 W 25 kHz
03  462.6125    FRS 3   500 mW  12.5 kHz    GMRS 11 5 W 25 kHz
04  462.6375    FRS 4   500 mW  12.5 kHz    GMRS 12 5 W 25 kHz
05  462.6625    FRS 5   500 mW  12.5 kHz    GMRS 13 5 W 25 kHz
06  462.6875    FRS 6   500 mW  12.5 kHz    GMRS 14 5 W 25 kHz
07  462.7125    FRS 7   500 mW  12.5 kHz    GMRS 15 5 W 25 kHz
08  467.5625    FRS 8   500 mW  12.5 kHz
09  467.5875    FRS 9   500 mW  12.5 kHz
10  467.6125    FRS 10  500 mW  12.5 kHz
11  467.6375    FRS 11  500 mW  12.5 kHz
12  467.6625    FRS 12  500 mW  12.5 kHz
13  467.6875    FRS 13  500 mW  12.5 kHz
14  467.7125    FRS 14  500 mW  12.5 kHz
15  462.5500                GMRS 1  50 W    25 kHz
16  462.5750                GMRS 2  50 W    25 kHz
17  462.6000                GMRS 3  50 W    25 kHz
18  462.6250                GMRS 4  50 W    25 kHz
19  462.6500                GMRS 5  50 W    25 kHz  Use restricted near Canadian border
20  462.6750                GMRS 6  50 W    25 kHz  Unofficial emergency/traveler assistance channel (PL 141.3)
21  462.7000                GMRS 7  50 W    25 kHz  Use restricted near Canadian border
22  462.7250                GMRS 8  50 W    25 kHz

Comment: You may only use "Type Approved" radio/sets on FRS/GMRS frequencies. The OP mentions that the sets he is using are of the brand "Baofeng" which are NOT certified by [FCC](https://www.fcc.gov/general/family-radio-service-frs). Furthermore, the OP is indicating that he is not in the US, so the information given in this answer is giving an appropriate answer. For these reasons I will have to down vote.

Comment: Hello Louis, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com.  We appreciate your willingness to contribute, but please keep in mind that this site isn't like a typical chat forum.  In particular we're looking for the best possible answers to questions, which get saved for posterity.  The [tour](http://ham.stackexchange.com/tour) gives the basic idea.  Your information is somewhat relevant, but doesn't directly answer the question, which is why it got down-voted.  Contribute answers that do and we'll up-vote you!